# socket.io: How to send data to server when the socket disconnect?

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I want to send some data with `disconnect` emit when the socket is disconnected.
Is it possible to do this or i have to emit `disconnect` myself?
I'm using socket.io-1.0
 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may send data to node.js server just using simle XMLHTTPRequest and ajax. Server must listen one url for this (for example, via express).

Another way send disconnect event via websockets event.